# Why is voltage measured differently with respect to a point charge than with respect to a field?

Tags: electrostatics

As per my understanding, voltage can be measured in two ways:
$V = kq/r$, and
$V = Ed$
With the first one being measured with respect to a point charge, and the second one with respect to a field.

Electric potential with a point charge is defined to be zero at an infinite distance, while with a field, it is defined to be zero at distance zero. My question is then, why are they oppositely defined? If someone asked you if voltage is greater close or far, then what you’ll you say? Isn’t the electric field just made up of all the charges?

Edit: I’m doing this problem, where there is a field created by a point charge, and they are asking where the *electric potential* is greater, I would think that from the point charge formula, the closer point would have a higher potential, but the answer states that the farther point has a higher potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both equations are measuring the **potential difference between two points**. In the first equation, one of the points is fixed to be a point* that's infinitely far away from the point charge, and the other point is a distance $r$ from the point charge, while in the second equation, the two points are a distance $d$ apart. $V=Ed$ is also only strictly true if 1) the electric field in question has the same magnitude and direction everywhere (which is *not* the case for the electric field emitted by a point charge), and 2) you are only moving parallel to the electric field.

In short, in the first equation, the two points are always infnitely far apart and the electric field is non-uniform, while in the second equation, the two points are always *finitely* far apart and the electric field is *uniform*. There is a version of the second equation that applies in every situation, that is defined by a line integral in which you move along a path $C$:

$$\Delta V=-\int_C \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

Note that you can derive your first equation from this one if you take a path $C$ from a point a distance $r$ from the point charge to some point infinitely far away.

*Typically this is best understood as a point that is collinear with the line made by the point charge and the other point of interest, but since the field goes to zero at infinity, it doesn't actually matter.